# Getting error that Property size doesn't exists but I have selected attribute size

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am not able to understand that why I am getting this error. I have tried multiple times but getting same error. Tried same type of thing in my personal ADF environment it worked but here it's not working. Please let me know if I am wrong anywhere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can’t take a proper screenshot? The snipping tool will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried similar scenario with exits and size attributes in Get meta data activity. In the if, I have used the below expression.

```
@and(greater(activity('Get Metadata1').output.size,121),activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists)
```

I got same error.

[image]

Here, the only possible way that we get this error even when we gave the attributes in the Get meta data activity is, **if the file does not exist in the folder**.

[image]

Here, **I have given empty string for filename** which means file won't exists in the required folder. Now, **if you see the Get meta data activity** output, the `size` won't be there because the file not exists. The `exists` will be `false`.

[image]

So, when file won't exist, there won't be the `size` attribute in the activity output and this causes the error.

To avoid the error, first we need to check the file exists or not and then we need to check for the size condition.

Use the expression like below in the `if` to do that.

```
@and(activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists,greater(activity('Get Metadata1').output.size,121))
```

With this expression, when the file does not exist (exists is `false`), it won't check for the `size` and gives the `false` value. When the file exists, then only it will check the for its size.

**Sample when file not exists: **

[image]

It will execute the **True activities** if the file exists and size condition is true.